# How to bind validation errors to a request using MultiActionController?

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I've tried a lot to implement a validation inside a MultiActionController and it seems it's not plain sailing. 
I need to validate a form and, in case of failure, I want to redirect to the same form, displaying the errors and also being able to load some info from a database.
So basically I have this:

```
@RequestMapping("/addResponse.htm")
public ModelAndView addResponse(@ModelAttribute("responseDTO") ResponseDTO
             respDTO, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) { 

 ResponseFormValidator respValidator = new ResponseFormValidator();
 respValidator.validate(respDTO, result);

 if (result.hasErrors()) {
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:responseForm.htm?id=" + respDTO.getProjID());
 }
}
```

What I want is for the responseForm handler method to remember the errors resulted from the validation process (the Result Object)
Of course, I can copy and paste the logic from that method inside my if statement but I'm thinking it must be a better way than just copy and paste.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: `MultiActionController` and `@RequestMapping` are mutually exclusive. Which is it?

Comment: It's MultiActionController using annotations

Comment: @ariel_ro: Like I said, you can't use both, you use one or the other.

Comment: The class doesn't extend MultiActionController if this is what you are saying.

Comment: So why do you keep mentioning `MultiActionController`, if it doesn't extend it?

Comment: Because it acts like one. This is what I'm talking about: http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-multi-action-controller-using-annotation.html

Answer (score 0):

In Spring version prior to 3.1.x, if you want to pass object through a redirect, you have to make your controller "session" aware.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/portlet.html#portlet-controller
(part 16.9, look for @SessionAttribute)

But after it is your responsibility to clean the object(s) stored in session that you do not want to use anymore.

With Spring 3.1.x, the flashAttribute is a very useful mecanism and Spring does the job for that.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes

Hereunder a little code to show the principle:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("form") FormBean formBean) {

    // Set some properties if needed

    return "tiles-litools-mml";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String formAction( @Validated({MyValidator.class})
    @ModelAttribute("form") FormBean formBean,
    BindingResult validatorresult, Model model, Errors errors,
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    //redirect if any error
    if (validatorresult.hasErrors()){

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "MML session failed");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("form", formBean);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("validation", validatorresult);
        return "redirect:/app/tools/form"; // redirect to the form GET method

    }

    // TODO continue code for process the form (valid!)


}
```

I assume you do not extends MultiActionController.

Comment: Do i need to set the formBean if i do not use redirect ? I am currently turning of session for all my JSPs, and it seems that i cant get the errors to display by returning to the form page. It shows me the exception trace instead.